# Error trying to crop frames of a video in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I been trying working in a program that crop some parts of a frame in a video with opencv.
the first program works, but when i try to resize the cropped images at some point crash giving me this error:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-eirhwqtr/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:721: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

i read that i could be an error of windows, but i try it in Ubuntu and its was the same result, the program pick the data from a csv that saves [frame, x, y]

All its in the main(path, lent) function!

```
import os

import cv2

import csv

video_path = ''

rl = 0

label = 1


def main(path, lent):
    global video_path
    global rl
    global label
    rl = lent

    frames = []
    coord = []

    with open(path, "r") as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx == 0:
                video_path = row[0]
            else:
                frames.append(float(row[0]))
                coord.append((int(row[1]), int(row[2])))

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    if not video.isOpened():
        print("Error! No file found!")

    i = 0

    while i < len(frames):
        video.set(1, frames[i])
        ret, frame = video.read()
        img_resized = frame
        if not os.path.exists(f"src/data/{video_path[-10:-4]}/resized{rl}"):
            os.makedirs(f"src/data/{video_path[-10:-4]}/resized{rl}")
        else:
            print(i)
            img_resized = img_resized[(coord[i][1] - rl):(coord[i][1] + rl), (coord[i][0] - rl):(coord[i][0] + rl)]
            cv2.imwrite(f"src/data/{video_path[-10:-4]}/resized{rl}/frame{i}.jpg", img_resized)
        i += 1

    print("Success!")
    video.release()
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Image does not exist. The file is empty. Check to see that the video actually captured a frame or that your resize or crop is working properly. Typically you can either do img_resized.shape or cv2.imshow(img_resized) to inspect what you think you have captured, resized or cropped. Also to debug, you may want to separate the resize from the crop. Make them two commands and check each. You may want to print your coords to see that they are correct. Once you debug, you can remove the print, imshow, etc.

Comment: Hello! Thanks i going to check it. For example. I have 100 previosly cropped imgs it work for n images and "randomly" dont work at example image 75.

Comment: Perhaps you have run out of RAM or disk space or you have a bad image?